# How to use file bandwidth reservation (scheduled file IO) in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, performance, winapi, io

I need to implement an application that streams data from disk. It is important that the data throughput is fairly constant and is not interupted by any other activity on the disk.

From Windows Vista onwards, the [GetFileBandwidthReservation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364951%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [SetFileBandwidthReservation()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365537%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) functions have been introduced specifically for this purpose. However, I cannot get this to work. I've searched the internet but I cannot find much information on this (and no working code samples seem to exist online).

Code to reproduce:

```
HANDLE h = ::CreateFile(L"D:\\testfile", GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN, NULL);

DWORD periodMilliseconds, bytesPerPeriod, transferSize, numOutstandingRequests;
BOOL discardable;

BOOL result = ::GetFileBandwidthReservation(h, &periodMilliseconds, &bytesPerPeriod,
    &discardable, &transferSize, &numOutstandingRequests);

if (result == FALSE) // result is always false!
{
    DWORD reason = ::GetLastError(); // reason is always 1!
    std::cout << "Error: " << reason << std::endl;
}

result = ::CloseHandle(h);
```

The call to GetFileBandwidthReservation always returns FALSE which indicates a failure. GetLastError returns 1 which isn't very helpfull. If a try to invoke **Set**FileBandwithReservation I get the same result.

I am testing this on a PC with Windows Server 2008 SP2 (32-bit).

Does anybody have any idea of what I am doing wrong? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where'd you get SP3 for Server 2008?

Comment: What does GetLastError() return?

Comment: Typo fixed: SP2 instead of SP3

Comment: GetLastError returns 1 is helpful. It means the device driver doesn't support the feature. I think Han's answer is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires support from the disk device driver.  The kind of driver that you'd find in an upscale server, not a consumer level machine.  Ask more questions about this at serverfault.com

Comment: I've read articles (such as http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=484) that allude that this feature was added to enable media players to provide glitch-free video playback. Of course this purpose is defeated if it is only available in upscale servers. While the application I'm developing is no media player, the requirements are very much alike in this regard.

Comment: I dunno, maybe it will end up on my laptop someday.  This stuff usually does, eventually.  The article doesn't mention IOCTL_STORAGE_ALLOCATE_BC_STREAM, the I/O control code for bandwidth contracts that the driver needs to implement.  Maybe that's another thing to look for.